# Given two independent identically distributed random variables, determine the distributions of $V = \max\{X,Y\}$ and $U = \min\{X,Y\}$

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, density-function

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables with common distribution function $F$ and density function $f$. Show that $V = \max\{X,Y\}$ has distribution function $\textbf{P}(V \leq x) = F(x)^{2}$ and probability density function $f_{V}(x) = 2f(x)F(x), x\in\mathbb{R}$. Find the density function of $U = \min\{X,Y\}$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $V = \max\{X,Y\}$, it results that
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(V\leq x) = \textbf{P}(\max\{X,Y\}\leq x) = \textbf{P}(X\leq x, Y\leq x) = \textbf{P}(X\leq x)\textbf{P}(Y\leq x) = F(x)^{2}
\end{align*}

because $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Therefore
\begin{align*}
f_{V}(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}F(x)^{2} = 2F(x)F^{\prime}(x) = 2f(x)F(x)
\end{align*}

Finally, we have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(U \leq x) & = \textbf{P}(\min\{X,Y\}\leq x) = 1 - \textbf{P}(\min\{X,Y\} > x)\\\\
& = 1 - \textbf{P}(X > x,Y > x) = 1 - \textbf{P}(X>x)\textbf{P}(Y>x)\\\\
& = 1 - (1 - F(x))(1 - F(x)) = F(x) + F(x) - F(x)F(x)\\\\
& = F(x)(2 - F(x))
\end{align*}

Could someone double-check my calculations? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, they seem correct (you have not found the density of $U$ yet, though). Note also that $X+Y=U+V$ (right?), hence $P(U\le x)=P(X+Y-V\le x)$. Now, observe that $$P(X+Y-V\le x)\overset{??}=P(X\le x)+P(Y\le x)-P(V\le x)=2F(x)-F^2(x)$$ Although the first equality cannot be justified, it does indeed hold (as you calculated) surprisingly enough!